# Flask dev server with threads enabled serving a flask-sqlalchemy app becomes very unstable

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We are developing a Flask application that relies heavily on the `flask-sqlalchemy` integration module. SQLAlchemy is used to connect to our MonetDB database.

When running the application via the command

```
flask run
```

the service irregularly but often hangs on various strange database client site symptoms related to the database communication, e.g. database connection closed, failed to decode some character, and other hard to interpret errors.

I know that by default, Flask's Werkzeug development server has threads enabled and when we run the development server without threads

```
flask run --disable-threads
```

the service works like a charm without any errors.

Scanning our codebase, I think we are configuring and using `flask-sqlalchemy` in a straight forward way:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[environment])
db.init_app(app)
```

we propagate updates to the database with calls that typically look like.

```
...
db.create_all()
db.session.add(foo)
db.session.add(bar)
...
db.session.commit()
```

As far as I know the session member of the `SqlAlchemy` `db` object is a `ScopedSession` instance and therefore it should be a thread-local and therefore thread safe object. But nonetheless we get trouble with the above mentioned errors.

The only thing I can imagine is that sometimes database modifications are not always directly followed by a db.session.commit(), i.e. we forget to call session.commit(). But I don't see how that would lead to these multi-threading issues.

Comment: I assume that the db transactions with `db.session.commit()` are blocking the thread from continuing to work which *could* lead to instability. Is it required to run it single-threaded? As long as you are in a development environment that shouldn't need to reflect the deployment system, IMO.

Comment: In production we are running the application in gunicorn. The gunicorn server spawns multiple processes instead of threads. And so far this works fine. Which doesn't surprise me. For development purposes, its not required perse to run the application **multi-threaded** if that's what you mean. But I feel a lot more comfortable if somebody could point out a possible reason for this behavior when we actually do use threads in our dev server. Based on my understanding of the documentation, it seems we are not doing something clearly wrong here.